# Deleting all occurrences of element in a nested list in prolog

Tags: list, data-structures, prolog

I am trying to delete a specific element from a nested list.

`delete(X,L,L1)` to delete all occurrences of `X` from a list `L` producing the list `L1`. For exmaple:

```
?- delete(a,[a,b,[a,d],c],L1). will give us 
[b,[d],c].
```

I am able to remove the element from a simple non nested list but can't figure out how to remove it in the inner list.

My code:

```
deletelist(Xs,[],Xs).

deletelist(Xs,[Y|Ys],Zs):- delete(Xs,Y,As),
deletelist(As,Ys,Zs).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to think about your predicates more carefully. What you have seems a bit random. `deletelist(Xs, [], Xs)` says if you delete `Xs` from an empty list, you get `Xs`. That isn't right. It should be that if you delete *anything* from an empty list, you get an empty list. That is, `deletelist(_, [], []).` our recursive clause is also not thought out. Just think through it more carefully and try again. If you have `deletelist(X, [X|Xs], R)...` what would `R` be? And what if you have `deletelist(X, [Y|Ys], R)`? If `Y` is a list? If `Y` is not a list? Etc...

Comment: @lurker sorry I am just a beginner at prolog

Comment: @lurker how would I handle the case for the inner list?

Comment: One way is, in your `deletelist(X, [Y|Ys], R)` case, check if `Y` is a list using `is_list(Y)`. If `is_list(Y)` is true, then you need to `deletelist(X, Y, R1), ...` If it's not true (does not succeed), then you keep `Y` if `dif(X, Y)` (`X` and `Y` are different).

Comment: @lurker Okay so I changed my program to this. What do you think? I still cant figure out what to do to handle the inner list.

          delete(_,[],[]).
          delete(X,[X|L],M) :- !, delete(X,L,M).
          delete(X,[Y|L1],[Y|L2]) :- delete(X,L1,L2).

Comment: I think you need to edit your question with your updated code, not put it in a comment. It will be easier to read, and easier to get help. :) But at a quick glance, your `delete(X, [Y|L1], [Y|L2])` doesn't ensure that `X` and `Y` are different, and doesn't check whether `Y` is a list. Those are two things I mentioned in my prior comment.