# Nested list item deletion in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on this Prolog code to delete all occurrences of an element in a list, nested lists included. However instead of deleting the element it replaces it with an empty list.

Here is my code:

```
del(Item, [Head|Tail], [HeadResult|TailResult]) :-
   del(Item, Head, HeadResult),
   del(Item,Tail,TailResult), 
   !. 
del(Item,[], []). 
del(Item, Item, []). 
del(Item, Head, Head).
```

I believe the line `del(Item,[], []).` to be the culprit. However I am not sure how to change so that it doesn't appear in my new list.

Example of wanted output:

```
remberD(a, [a,b,c,[a,b]], New).

New = [b,c,[b]].
```

Comment: This question was also asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757202/deleting-all-occurrences-of-element-in-a-nested-list-in-prolog). You might want to read through some of the comments.

Comment: Try to think logically. If `del(X, Y, Z)` is a predicate in which element `X` is removed from list of lists `Y` yielding result `Z`, then clearly `del(Item, Item, []).` doesn't make sense since the second argument shouldn't be the same as the item being deleted. Perhaps you mean, `del(Item, [Item], []).` And `del(Item, Head, Head)` says if I delete `Item` from any list, I get the same list back. That doesn't seem logical either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting a structural recursion with

```erlang
del(Item, [Head|Tail], [HeadResult|TailResult]) :-  % wrong
   del(Item, Head, HeadResult),
   del(Item, Tail, TailResult).
```

Seems good, except, what if `Head = Item`? The result should just be `TailResult` in such a case, there shouldn't be any `HeadResult` there at all:

```erlang
del(Item, [Item|Tail], TailResult):-
   del(Item, Tail, TailResult).
```

Now, what if it's not an `Item` at the input list's head? Two cases - either it's a list and we need to go inside it, or it's not a list and we just keep it as it is:

```erlang
del(Item, [Head|Tail], [HeadResult|TailResult]) :- 
   Head \= Item, Head = [_|_],
   del(Item, Head, HeadResult),
   del(Item, Tail, TailResult).

del(Item, [Head|Tail], [Head|TailResult]) :- 
   Head \= Item, Head \= [_|_],
   del(Item, Tail, TailResult).
```

The only other case is trying to delete something from an empty list:

```erlang
del(_, [], []).
```

This assumes you'll always call this predicate with fully instantiated terms.